# To find the finite summation of negative binomial.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, geometric-series, negative-binomial

I'm looking to simplify the following expression. Basically need to remove the summation up to $t$

$$\sum_{k=j}^t \binom{k-1}{j-1} p^{k-j} q^j$$

where $p=1-q$, $t$ is a large finite number like $10^{15}$, $k\geq j$, $2\leq j\leq 50$.

Thanks

Comment: Your $q$ must be small enough for $10^{15}$ to make a significant difference from $\infty$. Is it?

Comment: yes q is very small positive fraction.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the summation up to $t$". Do you need the value of the sum for infinite $t$?

Comment: so I came across the formula $$\sum_{k=0}^\inf \binom{k+j-1}{j-1} p^k = (1+p)^{-j}$$. The proof is here https://gotohaggstrom.com/The%20binomial%20series%20for%20negative%20integral%20exponents.pdf. I was wondering if a similar simplification can be done for a finite summation.

Comment: The correct version is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases).

Comment: Thank you @metamorphy. They look similar. My problem is that I cannot directly code the calculation as t is very large. Which is why I need the simplification.

Comment: Mathematica says: `p^j ((1 - p) p)^-j q^j - (1 - p)^j p^(1 + t) ((1 - p) p)^-j q^
  j Binomial[t, -1 + j] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + t, 2 - j + t, p]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I tried the same in Mathematica. But it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we note:
$$
{d^j \over dx^j}\frac{x^k}{1-x}=j!\sum_{i=0}^j\binom ki\frac{x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+1}}.\tag1
$$

Then we have for $j\ge1$:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k-1}{j-1} p^{k-j}q^{j}
&=\frac{q^j}{(j-1)!}\sum_{k=j}^n{d^{j-1} \over dp^{j-1}}p^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{q^j}{(j-1)!}{d^{j-1} \over dp^{j-1}}\sum_{k=j}^np^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{q^j}{(j-1)!}{d^{j-1} \over dp^{j-1}}\frac{p^{j-1}-p^{n}}{1-p}\\
&\stackrel{(1)}=q^j\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\frac{\binom{j-1}ip^{j-1-i}-\binom{K}ip^{n-i}}{q^{j-i}}\\
&=
p^{j-1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}i\left(\frac qp\right)^i
-p^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{n}i\left(\frac qp\right)^i\\
&=1-\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{n}i p^{n-i}q^i.\tag2
\end{align}$$

Thus, to obtain the same result you can compute using (2) much shorter sum (according to $j\le50$).

---

A simple combinatorial proof of the identity:
$$
\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom{i-1}{k-1} p^{k}q^{i-k}=1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{i}p^{i}q^{n-i}
$$
can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695236).

---

**Appendix**. Proof of the equation (1) by induction.

Obviously the equation holds for $j=0$. Assume that it holds for some $j$. Then it holds for $j+1$ as well:
$$\begin{align}
{d^{j+1} \over dx^{j+1}}\frac{x^k}{1-x}&=\frac d{dx}\left[{d^{j} \over dx^{j}}\frac{x^k}{1-x}\right]\\
&\stackrel{I.H.}=\frac d{dx}\left[j!\sum_{i=0}^j\binom ki\frac{x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+1}}\right]\\
&=j!\sum_{i=0}^j\binom ki
\left[\frac{(k-i)x^{k-i-1}}{(1-x)^{j-i+1}}
+\frac{(j-i+1)x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
\right]\\
&=j!\sum_{i=0}^j\left[\binom k{i+1}\frac{(i+1)x^{k-i-1}}{(1-x)^{j-i+1}}
+\binom k{i}\frac{(j-i+1)x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
\right]\\
&=j!\left[\sum_{i=1}^{j+1}\binom k{i}
\frac{i\,x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
+\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom k{i}\frac{(j-i+1)x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
\right]\\
&=j!\left[\sum_{i=0}^{j+1}\binom k{i}
\frac{i\,x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
+\sum_{i=0}^{j+1}\binom k{i}\frac{(j-i+1)x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}
\right]\\
&=(j+1)! \sum_{i=0}^{j+1}\binom k{i}\frac{x^{k-i}}{(1-x)^{j-i+2}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The formula you use at beginning when you mentioned - first we note, can I get the proof/link of that?

Comment: @ovia You have already accepted  another answer. Do you really need the proof?

Comment: The other answer was a bit more complicated than I thought. If can I prove this rigorously I would prefer to implement this one.  Also as a follow-up, I would like to know what happens when it $\sum_{i=0}^n$ instead of $\sum_{i=k}^n$ on the LHS

Comment: @ovia I have added the proof of equation (1). But as already said the main result has a very simple combinatorial (probabilistic) proof, so that all the machinery is in fact unnecessary for your particular problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no closed form w.r.t. *both* $t$ and $j$, but for a fixed $j$, you can use $$\sum_{k=j}^{t}\binom{k-1}{j-1}x^{k-j}=\frac{1}{(j-1)!}\frac{d^{j-1}}{dx^{j-1}}\frac{1-x^t}{1-x},$$ giving a sum of only $\,\approx\!j$ terms after applying the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives). Another approach is to consider the $t\to\infty$ asymptotics of your expression, assuming $q=q(t)$ is known.

Comment: this will help me. Can you please share the link of its proof?

Comment: @ovia: Isn't it obvious? $\frac{1-x^t}{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^{t}x^{k-1}$. Now take $(j-1)$-th derivative...

Comment: yes got it. Thank you.